# Prove this inequality about ln

Tags: calculus

for a>0 can someone give me some clues to prove this inequality.

[image]

I found its derivative but I can't express the f(0) to use the Mean Value Theorem. Can you give me at least a point where to start at

Answer (score 1):

$\ln \frac{a+1}{a} = \ln(a+1) - \ln a$. Now you may use the Mean Value Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

By the mean value theorem there's $c\in(x,y)$ such that

$$\frac{y-x}{y}<\ln(y)-\ln(x)=(y-x)\frac1c<\frac{y-x}{x}$$
Now take $x=a$ and $y=1+a$ to conclude.